# мне нужно объединить 2 словаря в один(каждый создается из csv файла в двух функциях)

Tags: python-3.x, функции, dataframe, словари, передача-параметров

надо закинуть возвращаемые значения двух первых функций в 3 и объединить их.
понимаю, что решение где-то на поверхности, но никак не могу понять, как это сделать аккуратно и красиво. буду рад любой помощи, заранее спасибо
этот код без 3 функции с объединением

```
result: {1: 3.5, 2: 4.67}

lst_movie: 
[{'movieId': 1, 'year': '2018', 'title': 'Bungo Stray Dogs: Dead Apple (2018)', 'genres': 'Action|Animation', 'rating': None},
 {'movieId': 2, 'year': '1991', 'title': 'Andrew Dice Clay: Dice Rules (1991)', 'genres': 'Comedy', 'rating': None}]
```

в result закидываю значения по такой схеме {movieId: rating} и на место rating в lst_movie(который None) нужно поставить rating из result в соответствии с movieId. если в result нет rating к какому-то movieId, то остается None

```
import csv
import re
from collections import defaultdict as df


def csv_movie(file_obj):
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj)
    next(f_obj)
    lst_movie = []
    for row in reader:
        dic = dict()
        dic['movieId'] = int(row[0])
        dic['year'] = ''.join(re.findall('(?<=\()[0-9]{4}(?=\))', row[1]))
        dic['title'] = row[1]
        dic['genres'] = row[2]
        dic['rating'] = None
        lst_movie.append(dic)
    return lst_movie


def csv_rating(file):
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    lst = []
    next(obj)                #     8 строка    
    for row in reader:
        dic = dict()
        dic[int(row[1])] = float(row[2])
        lst.append(dic)
    d = df(list)
    for i in lst:
        for j in i.keys():
            d[j].append(i[j])
    result = {k: round(sum(v) / len(v), 2) for k, v in d.items()}
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_movies = "movies.csv"
    csv_ratings = "ratings.csv"
    with open(csv_movies, "r") as f_obj:
        csv_movie(f_obj)
    with open(csv_ratings, "r") as obj:
        csv_rating(obj)
```

**UPD**

добавил как вы посоветовали

```
def fill_movie_rating(lst_movie, result):
    for movie in lst_movie:
        movie['rating'] = result.get(movie['movieId'])
    print(lst_movie)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_movies = "movies.csv"
    csv_ratings = "ratings0.csv"
    with open(csv_movies, "r") as f_obj:
        csv_movie(f_obj)
        lst_movie = csv_movie(f_obj)      #   48 строка
    with open(csv_ratings, "r") as obj:
        csv_rating(obj)
        result = csv_rating(obj)
```

выдало ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 48, in <module>
    lst_movie = csv_movie(f_obj)
  line 8, in csv_movie
    next(f_obj)
StopIteration
```

если удалить из `main`, то ничего не выводится

Comment: Вы лучше покажите как выглядят словари (хотя бы по нескольку элементов из них) и что вы хотите из них получить. Что нам толку от кода генерации словарей, если у нас нет ваших `.csv` файлов.

Comment: добавил, спасибо

Comment: Разобрались? Не надо дважды вызывать одну и ту же функцию подряд в вашем случае, тем более это не работает. Логика такая: открыли файл, прочитали, закинули в функцию прочитанное, `return` которой передали переменной. И так всегда. Функцию `fill_movie_rating` так же можете вызывать в `main` после того как вы получили значения для переменных `lst_movie, result`

Answer (score 1):

В результате исполнения двух вышеописанных функции вы имеете двe переменных. Одна из них `lst_movie` (тип list), которая содержит общие данные о фильмах и вторая `result` (тип dict), в котором хранятся рейтинги фильмов.

Входные данные, которые будут использованы:

```py
lst_movie = [{'movieId': 193587, 'year': '2018', 'title': 'Bungo Stray Dogs: Dead Apple (2018)', 'genres': 'Action|Animation', 'rating': None}, {'movieId': 193609, 'year': '1991', 'title': 'Andrew Dice Clay: Dice Rules (1991)', 'genres': 'Comedy', 'rating': None}]

result = {193587: 3.5, 2: 4.67, 3: 4.33}
```

что будем делать? Брать значение `movieId` из `result` (который есть ключ), искать его в `lst_movie` и определять рейтинг, который соответствует `movieId`

```py
>>> for i in result:
...   for k in lst_movie:
...     if i == k["movieId"]:
...       k["rating"] = result[i]
```

И в итоге имеем:

```py
>>> print(lst_movie)
[{'movieId': 193587, 'year': '2018', 'title': 'Bungo Stray Dogs: Dead Apple (2018)', 'genres': 'Action|Animation', 'rating': 3.5}, {'movieId': 193609, 'year': '1991', 'title': 'Andrew Dice Clay: Dice Rules (1991)', 'genres': 'Comedy', 'rating': None}]
```

т.е. рейтинг фильма с `'movieId': 193587` изменился на 3.5

**UPD**
сама функция

```py
def union_dict(result:dict, lst_movie:list) -> list:
    for i in result:
        for k in lst_movie:
           if i == k["movieId"]:
               k["rating"] = result[i]
    return lst_movie
```

вызов

```py
union_dict(result, lst_movie)
```

Я бы так же обратил внимание на ответ от @CrazyElf. Он объективно лучше

Comment: а как возможно это решение закинуть в функцию? выполняя это задание, я обнаружил свою слабость в функциях, и основная моя проблема - это переменные lst_movie и result, которые локальные. я прошурстил не один сайт с описаниями работы с функциями, но ничего толкового не нашел. буду крайне признателен, если вы поможете мне

Comment: Ваш ответ в целом подробнее, но вот реально имея готовый словарь нет смысла делать цикл перебора его ключей, чтобы найти нужный, когда можно сразу взять значение по ключу.

Comment: @CrazyElf абсолютно согласен, при большом количестве данных слишком много не нужных итераций, да и при малом тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Если в `result` точно есть все `movieId` из `lst_movie`, то можно так:

```
def fill_movie_rating(lst_movie, result):
    for movie in lst_movie:
        movie['rating'] = result[movie['movieId']]
```

А если там есть не все `movieId`, то нужно делать через `get`, чтобы не выпало исключение:

```
def fill_movie_rating(lst_movie, result):
    for movie in lst_movie:
        movie['rating'] = result.get(movie['movieId'])
```

Comment: ну да, так естественно лучше. Одна вещь только про вариант номер 2: почему вы указываете вторым аргументом `None`? get же, все равно, если не найдет вернет его без явного указания. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Dmitry Да, вы правы. Просто указал такое же значение, как исходно было в словаре, на самом деле не знаю, что автору вопроса нужно там чтобы было

Comment: а как возможно это решение закинуть в функцию? выполняя это задание, я обнаружил свою слабость в функциях, и основная моя проблема - это переменные lst_movie и result, которые локальные. я прошурстил не один сайт с описаниями работы с функциями, но ничего толкового не нашел. буду крайне признателен, если вы поможете мне

Comment: @Platon Достаточно написать заголовок функции. Добавил.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за ответ, но я немного про другое: переменные result и lst_movie находятся внутри функций и "не видны" остальному коду. как их передать в def fill_movie_rating?

Comment: @Platon Так и передать: `fill_movie_rating(lst_movie, result)`, в данном случае названия внутренних переменных функции и внешних переменных, которые передаются функции, совпадают

Comment: @Platon у вас обе функции возвращают значения, так присвойте их переменным в `main`, например так `lst_movie=csv_movie(f_obj)`

Comment: @Dmitry я сделал как вы говорили, но выдало ошибку(дополнил вопрос)

Comment: @CrazyElf в таком случае ничего не выводиться, никаких ошибок нет(дополнил вопрос с учетом замечания @Dmitry)